# Java, diferença entre Integer.TYPE e int.class

Tags: java, reflexão

Qual a diferença entre utilizar `Integer.TYPE` e `int.class`?

Fiz alguns testes e ambos podem ser passados como parâmetro para um `Class<?>`.

Comment: Até onde eu saiba não há diferença, tratam-se da mesma `Class`. Se eu encontrar alguma referência confirmando isso, posto como resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Integer.TYPE e o int.class são a mesma coisa.

Se você executar o trecho a seguir, verá que o retorno é true.

```
System.out.println(Integer.TYPE.equals(int.class));
```

A definição do Integer.TYPE é a seguinte:

```
public static final Class<Integer>  TYPE = (Class<Integer>) Class.getPrimitiveClass("int");
```